# Combining two objects

Tags: javascript

Im looking for a way to combine the two objects into a single function or something that would lessing my line count.

> ```
> var fsInfo1 = {
>     name: 'Joshua Velez',
>     address:{
>         street: '94-1411 Kulewa Loop ',
>         city: 'Waipahu, ',
>         state: 'HI'
>     },
>     gpa: [3.3,4.0,2.8]
>
> }
> var fsInfo2= {
>     name: 'John Doe',
>     address:{
>         street: 'Some Street ',
>         city: 'Wahiawa, ',
>         state: 'HI'
>     },
>     gpa: [3.4,3.6,3.1]
> }
> ```
>
> console.log("Name: " + fsInfo1.name)
>
> console.log("Address: " + fsInfo1.address['street'] + fsInfo1.address['city'] + fsInfo1.address['state'])
> console.log("GPA: " + fsInfo1.gpa[0],fsInfo1.gpa[1],fsInfo1.gpa[2])
>
> console.log("Name: " + fsInfo2.name)
>
> console.log("Address: " + fsInfo2.address['street'] + fsInfo2.address['city'] + > fsInfo2.address['state'])
> console.log("GPA: " + fsInfo2.gpa[0],fsInfo2.gpa[1],fsInfo2.gpa[2])

Comment: An array will only save you the fsInfo2= string: 
var arr = [{
    name: 'Joshua Velez',
    address:{
        street: '94-1411 Kulewa Loop ',
        city: 'Waipahu, ',
        state: 'HI'
    },
    gpa: [3.3,4.0,2.8]

},
 {
    name: 'John Doe',
    address:{
        street: 'Some Street ',
        city: 'Wahiawa, ',
        state: 'HI'
    },
    gpa: [3.4,3.6,3.1]
}]

Comment: Which linecount are you trying to reduce? Your objects are still going to contain the data. You can create a loop to go through them if you make them into an array

Comment: no specific line count just think its to much code which can be simplified

Comment: And perhaps more to the point, WHY are you trying to reduce line count?  There might be some valid reasons to refactor this code, (for example, you might define a function to do the output), but "fewer lines" shouldn't be one of them.

Comment: Yes I need later on I need to add another person with same info with this function addData('John Doe', '42 Walibi Way', 'Sydney', 'AU', [3.4,3.0,3.7])

Comment: What function is that?  If you can give some more detail in the question of what you're trying to do exactly, that would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is:

```
var fsInfo1 = // same as before
var fsInfo2 = // same 
function logFsInfo(fsInfo) {
    console.log("Name "+fsInfo.name);
    console.log("Address "+fsInfo.address.street + fsInfo.address.city + fsInfo.address.state);
    console.log("GPA "+fsInfo.gpa.join(",")); //combine gpa values into a string separated by commas
}
logFsInfo(fsInfo1);
logFsInfo(fsInfo2);
```

But it really depends on what you want to do here.  Is all you're doing printing out fsInfo data?  If so, sure, just do something like this as a shortcut to printing out that data.  But if you want to start doing other things with fsInfo objects, I'd suggest making a class and attaching methods to it.  But, that would be complete overkill for a simple use.

Answer (score 0):

```
var fsInfo1 = {
    name: 'Joshua Velez',
    address:{
        street: '94-1411 Kulewa Loop ',
        city: 'Waipahu, ',
        state: 'HI'
    },
    gpa: [3.3,4.0,2.8]

}
var fsInfo2= {
    name: 'John Doe',
    address:{
        street: 'Some Street ',
        city: 'Wahiawa, ',
        state: 'HI'
    },
    gpa: [3.4,3.6,3.1]
}
var obj = new Object();

obj[0] = fsInfo1;
obj[1] = fsInfo2;
var count = Object.keys(myArray).length;
for(i=0 ; i<count;i++)
{
      console.log("Name: " + obj[i].name)

console.log("Address: " + obj[i].address['street'] + obj[i].address['city'] + obj[i].address['state']) console.log("GPA: " + obj[i].gpa[0],obj[i].gpa[1],obj[i].gpa[2])
}
```

Comment: In which part you want explanation?